# Create Filter Examples rapidminer Operator in java

Tags: java, rapidminer

i need some help creating a java project connected to rapidminer. I need to create a new process and a Filter Examples operator in order to filter some text with random words which i cannot do using only Rapidminer. I can't find anywhere how to create that specific operator in java and how to add the text and the random words. Can anyone help? Is there a specific piece of code for this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

the standard "How to extend Rapidminer" documentation can be found here:
https://rapidminer.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/How-to-Extend-RapidMiner-5.pdf

At Rapidminer Wisdom it was announced that there is a gradle project to make it easier to start. Sadly i have no direct link yet.